# convert Emgu.CV.mat into System.drawing.image?

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I want to do some image processing using EMGU and visualize the result
in a Winform application. So after the image processing I have to convert the CV.MAT into System.drawing.image to make it work with winform.
   How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out how to do it.

```
mat.ToImage<Bgr,Byte>().ToBitmap();
```